# how to check if a hash is empty in perl

Tags: perl, hash

I use the following code to check if the hash is empty. Is there a better method and is this safe to use?

```
if (!keys %hash) { print "Empty";}
```

Answer (score 105):

```
if (%hash)
```

Will work just fine.

From [perldoc perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html):

> If you evaluate a hash in scalar context, it returns false if the hash
>   is empty. If there are any key/value pairs, it returns true; more
>   precisely, the value returned is a string consisting of the number of
>   used buckets and the number of allocated buckets, separated by a
>   slash.

Comment: It seems much slower than `keys %hash`.

Comment: Good answer: What I was missing was the reference where the semantics are defined (it is not in `perlop`).

Comment: @choroba Do you also have an explanation and numbers (Perl version) for it?

Comment: @U.Windl: It has recently changed, so in the current Perl version(s), %hash in scalar context is equivalent to `keys %hash`.

Comment: Seems [`!%h` was optimized some more in 5.26](https://perldoc.perl.org/perl5260delta#Performance-Enhancements). [`scalar keys` performance was improved in 5.28](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/commit/6f2dc9a6b978e866e22c46235932d018da8262ba).

Answer (score 28):

There was [a bug](https://rt.perl.org/rt3/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=22973) which caused tied hashes in scalar context to always return false.  The bug was [fixed in 5.8.5](https://github.com/mirrors/perl/commit/a3bcc51ebd4e201d85a37d8410b7a375b8d94244).  If you're concerned with backwards compatibility that far back I would stick with `if( !keys %hash )`.  Otherwise use `if( !%hash )` as recommended by others.

Comment: Being paranoid I used `scalar keys %hash == 0` as test. So `!keys ...` is basically doing a test on an array, not on a hash.

Comment: @U.Windl Yes, `keys %hash` returns an array. `scalar keys %hash` returns an integer. Note that Perl functions are context aware and can optimize. `!%hash` is optimized to return a boolean. It does not iterate through its keys, it already has a count. The code is a nightmare, but [here's the optimization](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/e2737abbb702a05e83f4aa2486a941ac3964446a/pp_hot.c#L1807). `i = HvUSEDKEYS(hv);`

Answer (score 22):

Simpler:

```
if (!%hash) { 
    print "Empty";
}
```

`!` imposes a scalar context, and hash evaluated in a scalar context returns:

- *false* if there are zero keys (not defined in the documentation but experimentally returns `0`)

Depending on the version of Perl, either of the following:

- A string signifying how many used/allocated buckets are used for >0 keys, which will of course be NOT false (e.g. "3/6").
  (Non-empty string evaluate to *true*)
- The number of keys in the hash (as explained in `perldata`: "*As of Perl 5.25 the return was changed to be the count of keys in the
  hash. If you need access to the old behavior you can use
  "Hash::Util::bucket_ratio()" instead.*")

Comment: No it doesn't return `"false"`, which would be a true value. It returns zero.

Answer (score 2):

"Better" is a subjective term. However I would argue that code that is easier to understand can be described as "better". For this reason I conclude that `!keys %hash` is better, because everybody writing perl code will know what this code does and that it works. `!%hash` is something at least I would have to look up to ensure if it really works or only looks like it would work. (The reason being that the return value of a hash in scalar context is rather confusing while an arrays behavior in scalar context is well known and often used.)

Also, `!keys %hash` is safe.

So no, there is no better or safer way to check if a hash is empty.

Comment: I agree: While thinking `if (%hash)` might work, I tried to find the specification of the semantics. Probably the confusing part is that `if (@array)` seems to be more clearly defined, but for symmetry it *should* work for hashes, too. Maybe that is why they changed it recently.