# Perl set boolean if hash map is empty

Tags: perl

I'm just starting out with perl. I want to set a boolean variable flag based on if the hash map has content or not. This tells me I can use a ! operator to check if hash empty. [how to check if a hash is empty in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444915/how-to-check-if-a-hash-is-empty-in-perl)

So I have this so far:

```
if (!%someHash){
    $flag = false;
} else {
    $flag = true;
}
```

Is this a best way of writing it or there is a simpler way?

Comment: Don't use barewords (`false`, `true`); do use `use strict;` and `use warnings;` which would have told you about barewords.  Use: `$flag = !%someHash;` to set the variable.  Or use `0` in place of `false` and `1` in place of `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Since perl doesn't have boolean types I've always just done:

```
my $flag = keys %someHash
```