# Perl Module Error - defined(%hash) is deprecated

Tags: linux, perl, hash, cron, perl-module

**Background:**

- I am working to migrate a Linux server to a newer one from Ubuntu 10.04 to 12.04
- This server is responsible for executing several a number of Perl modules via crontabs.
- These Perl Modules rely heavily on 30-40 perl extensions.
- I have installed all Perl extensions and the crontabs are able to process successfully except for several Syntax errors caused by the newer versions of these Perl extensions.
- I need some help with modifying the syntax to get the Perl script to process as intended.

Errors:

```
defined(%hash) is deprecated at pm/Alerts/Alerts.pm line 943.
        (Maybe you should just omit the defined()?)
defined(%hash) is deprecated at pm/Alerts/Alerts.pm line 944.
        (Maybe you should just omit the defined()?)
```

Code:

```
###
    # Iterate the arrays deleting identical counts from each.
    # If we found a mismatch then die.
    # If either array is not empty when we are done then die
    $logger->info('Comparing ' . (scalar keys %cms_rows) . ' CMS symbols to ' . (scalar keys %stats_rows) . ' STATS symbols');

    foreach my $symbol ( keys %cms_rows ) {
    my %cms_row = delete $cms_rows{$symbol};
    my %stats_row = delete $stats_rows{$symbol};

##LINE 943##    die("Error: NULL CMS counts for symbol '$symbol'") unless defined %cms_row;
##LINE 944##    die("Error: NULL Stats counts for symbol '$symbol'") unless defined %stats_row;

    my $cms_json = encode_json(\%cms_row);
    my $stats_json = encode_json(\%stats_row);
    $logger->debug("Comparing counts for '$symbol': CMS($cms_json), Stats($stats_json)");

    die("Error: Up Counts Don't match for symbol '$symbol': CMS($cms_json), Stats($stats_json)") unless (!defined $cms_row{1} && !defined $stats_row{1}) || $cms_row{1} == $stats_row{1};
    die("Error: Down Counts Don't match for symbol '$symbol': CMS($cms_json), Stats($stats_json)") unless (!defined $cms_row{-1} && !defined $stats_row{-1}) || $cms_row{-1} == $stats_row{-1};
    }
    ###
```

Hopefully someone can help with this, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just to be clear: The newer versions of Perl has not *caused* errors, they have just shown you that they exist. Also that is a non-fatal warning, not a syntax error. I assume that the point is to check if the hash is empty or not, in which case you can just use `unless %hash`. Like this answer shows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444915/how-to-check-if-a-hash-is-empty-in-perl/9444942#9444942

Answer (score 10):

You must have upgraded from a seriously old version of Perl. The Perl [5.6.1 release notes](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perl561delta.pod) say:

> defined(%hash) is deprecated
>
> (D) defined() is not usually useful on hashes because it checks for an
>   undefined scalar value. If you want to see if the hash is empty, just
>   use `if (%hash) { # not empty }` for example.

It was always a pretty stupid thing to do and Perl now warns you that you're doing something stupid. The warning is pretty clear about what you should do to fix this:

> Maybe you should just omit the defined()?

So your lines would become:

```
die("Error: NULL CMS counts for symbol '$symbol'") unless %cms_row;
die("Error: NULL Stats counts for symbol '$symbol'") unless %stats_row;
```

Comment: Just to quantify "seriously old," Perl 5.6.1 was released all the way back in April 2001!

Comment: Thanks. I meant to include that information in my answer, but it slipped my mind.

Comment: Thank you so much Dave this worked, guess if I would have read a bit more closely, I would have came up with this answer on my own. :) But not being a PERL programmer I didn't want to chance it. I actually just checked the version and its Perl 5.10.0 I believe its from 2007 still pretty old :(. This is one out of 30 different errors out of which I only have 4 left. luckily I was able to solve the rest with google. Thanks again. Happy Holidays.

Comment: Why are you upgrading to such an old version of Perl?

Comment: Oh no, sorry for not making myself clear I am upgrading from Perl 5.10.0 to Perl 5.14.2. I'm basically migrating the server to a new cloud platform. The site I'm working with runs on proprietary code and custom modules created a few years back when we had in house programmers. That is no longer the case, luckily I've managed to work around the code and get it done with very few errors remaining.